# Remember opend Tabs and its Content using Sessions

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, session

I have some Bootstrap Tabs in which I've dynamically loaded some Content via jQuery's load(). Additionally, if you click on a Button, a new Tab will be automatically build, filled with some Content (which is just a basic HTML-Form with various input fields) and finally append to the tab-header. What I'm now trying to do is to save

- how many Tabs are opend
- the Content (more detailed: The current text of the input fields) of each Tab
- and which Tab was active before refreshing the page

in a Session so that I'am able to rebuild the Tabs.

Has anyone of you any suggestion how to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want this information to be tracked as the user is opening tabs? Or does the user have to click a button to save their state before closing or navigating somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

Your application needs to allow users to have individual user accounts so you can restore that data (their [tab] preferences, if I may call them that) from their user account each time they return to your website.  Since you're using jQuery for a dynamic web experience already, you can easily use the `$.ajax()` features of jQuery to keep the user's preferences up-to-date using your own private API's.

### Explanation

I suggest that you develop a private web API using XHR (XHTTPRequest).  jQuery supports this with the `$.ajax()` and other functions.  Since you're already using sessions, you have some degree of persistence in place already.  If you are dealing with anonymous users (perhaps due to limitations in your web app's existing infrastructure or architecture), there is no reliable way to permanently store that information.  If you want that data to persist unto the next time the user visits, that data must be stored permanently on your server.  Your user must be authenticated for this to happen, though (user name, password) or you won't have any way of knowing which return visitor to restore that data for in a future session.